# How to configure VPN in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I'm planning to move to ubuntu from windows, but I don't know how to configure VPN in ubuntu.

On windows, the VPN provider has provided a GUI application, I just need to input my username and password, then choose a server in a list, everything is done.

But I input the same information into ubuntu, in the following dialog:

[image: vpn-dialog]

But it can't connect to server, the error message is:

[image: vpn-error]

(PS: I'm running the ubuntu in Virual-Box with default settings, and the type should be PPTP)

How to configure it correctly?

Comment: First, find out the VPN type. Cisco? OpenVPN? PPTP? IPsec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact specifics of your VPN server, I can't really say for sure.

However, if it is a Windows VPN server you are connecting to (PPTP) I wrote a blog post about it... [Click Here to read](http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2010/09/connecting-ubuntu-or-other.html)

Basically, go to your Windows box and try to copy all the settings you can find, in particular the security/encryption details.

If you are using a Windows VPN, here are the pictures from my blog post on how I set up Ubuntu to connect to my VPN server:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, still can't connect. Do you know how to see the detailed log?

Comment: @Freewind Do you have access to the VPN server?

Comment: Check your logs - sometimes you'll get more information from them about what the failure is.

Comment: @Broam, I'm not familiar with ubuntu, could you tell me how to check the logs? Where is the log file?

Comment: System -> Administration -> Log File Viewer if you want graphical. If you want to browse the files yourself, check `/var/log`

Comment: @William, your solution works well in a ubuntu installed on a real computer(not in VirtualBox)

Comment: @Freewind - Virtual shouldn't really make a difference (Look at the picture, I was just virtualbox!) Just make sure you are in bridged and not NAT - I don't see why it shouldn't work, but, that is the scenario when I tested.

Comment: @William, my virtualbox is in NAT

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try ensuring that "Allow Stateful Encryption" is checked (in addition to the above screenshot settings)